# isset function undesired result

Tags: php, forms, function, isset

```
<?php
if(isset($_REQUEST['fname'],$_REQUEST['age'],$_REQUEST['lname']))
{
    $file=fopen("guns.txt","w");
    $str1=$_POST["fname"];
    $str2=$_POST["lname"];
    $age=$_POST["age"];
    $chr="pussy";
    $cat="cat";
    vfprintf($file,"%s %s is %d years old",array($str1,$str2,$age));
    echo sprintf("HEY check out %1\$s %1\$s %2\$s %2\$s",$chr,$cat);
    fclose($file);
}
else
{
    echo "<form action='hill.php' method='post'>
    Enter your First Name:<input type='text' name='fname'></input><br>
    Enter your Last Name:<input type='text' name='lname'></input><br>
    Enter your Age:<input type='text' name='age'></input><br>
    <input type='submit' value='Submit'></input>
    </form>";
}
?>
```

the given code is from **hill.php** file

I dont know what's wrong but my isset function is not working properly
I want all the Entries to be filled then only proceeding to echoing the message entering the if statement.

Please help me.

Comment: define *isn't working properly*...

Comment: What exactly is the problem? "isn't working properly" is not a very good description. What does it do wrong? What are your `$_REQUEST` variables actually set to (have you checked using `print_r` or `var_dump` to confirm that they're what you expect?)

Comment: @RocketHazmat No it doesn't http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

Comment: @MathieuImbert: I.... I didn't know that.

Comment: @RocketHazmat - that's what I thought too, but I double-checked the manual and it clearly allows multiple variables. (having said that, I'd always use it with a single variable at a time)

Comment: @RocketHazmat ahahah I know, I made the same mistake a few weeks ago. It.. blew my mind, all this time I made the wrong assumption and wrote incredibly ugly `isset($var1) && isset($var2) && isset($var3) && ...`

Comment: @RocketHazmat the problem is that i dont want anyone to see the message PUssy cat ... and creation of file till the user fills in all the details in the form thats why i  used isset().But my isset is not working properly and message is being displayed without entry of even one variable ie. fname,lname or age .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be good to use `empty()` [(docs)](http://php.net/empty) instead, which will return true for things like empty strings and null. `isset()` will return true for some "falsy" values if the array key is there.

But we should note that simply validating existence of a value should not be considered appropriate input validation. You will likely want to introduce more semantic validation for each field (e.g. is "age" an integer?)

Comment: Isset only returns false for NULL, not for empty strings. It's unlikely $_REQUEST would hold a NULL value.

Comment: @Evert exactly. It is more likely that they contain empty strings, which is why I recommended empty. I edited my answer to remove "and null", thanks for the tip.

Comment: empty() can/will blow up on you if an "allowed" value is `0`. `empty(0) == true`. It's a braindead function that should be avoided.

Comment: @MarcB now there's a compelling reason to avoid it. Good note, thanks! I never really advocate for "simple" validation like this (hence the note in my answer). I hope OP reads your comment :-)

Comment: if(!empty($_REQUEST['fname'])&&!empty($_REQUEST['age'])&&!empty($_REQUEST['lname']))...I changed my if condition and now my code's working fine... Thanks all you guys .I really appreciate you all.

Answer (score 2):

You are using vprintf() incorrectly. It does **NOT** output to a file handle. The format is:

```
vprintf($format_string, array($args));
```

RTLM: http://php.net/vprintf

You should have, instead:

```
$formatted = vprintf('%this %that', array($this, $that));
$alt_format = sprintf('%this %that', $this, $that); // alternative
file_put_contents('yourfile.txt', $formatted);
```

Comment: @Mark B sir i dont think there is any problem in vfprintf .It is working the right way.You can check out http:\\www.w3schools.com and search for vfprintf().The syntax is same as i wrote.I feel the problem is in the isset().

Comment: @chetanmehta: w3fools is a useless piece of crap. I linked to the actual PHP site documentation (the **OFFICIAL** docs, not the pathetic garbage that w3morons spews), which clearly state that no filehandle is passed via vprintf()'s arguments. And if you'd bothered to read the w3fools, it **ALSO** doesn't mention anything about a file handle.

Comment: Sir I dnt know whether you are doing it deliberatly or incidently but you have everytime mistakenly written my VFPRINTF() as vprintf().Ther are seperate .And even in W3schools vprintf() the same as you wrote about.

Answer (score 0):

Check your error log.
Running the code above results in:

```
Warning: fopen(guns.txt) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in ... on line 4

Warning: vfprintf() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in ... on line 10
HEY check out pussy pussy cat cat
Warning: fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in ... on line 12
```

Your isset function *is* working properly.  Also, before your question was edited, you had a `'` before the `?>` at the end.

Comment: I request your views Sir.But more or less i am always directed into the if() statement given above except the first time when i submit the forms giving all entries, So a file 'guns.txt' is getting made in the specified www directory of wamp. And the file is displaying the same result as wanted.Everythings all right in file.